# Time series prediction, make new X, new row from some past rows

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

For times series prediction I am using pandas.

this is a some sample of my data frame:

```
                    Close Price
```

DateTime
2017-01-02 23:00:00     1.04630
2017-01-02 23:30:00     1.04575
2017-01-03 00:00:00     1.04672
2017-01-03 00:30:00     1.04662
2017-01-03 01:00:00     1.04766
......

in my X matrix for sklearn prediction I want to have something like this:
use 3 past row as input for making a new row
X:
                        ClosePrice    ClosePrice-1  ClosePrice-2 ClosePrice-3
2017-01-03 00:30:00     1.04662       1.04672       1.04575      1.04630
2017-01-03 01:00:00     1.04766       1.04662       1.04672      1.04575
...

what is the best method?
is there a way to use pandas function to do this?

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot
if I want to use n instead of 3 what is best method?

this is worked:

for i in range(1, NumberOfLastData):

```
ColunmNameHighLowBin   = 'HighLowBin-'   + str(i)
ColunmNameOpenCloseBin = 'OpenCloseBin-' + str(i)

X[ColunmNameHighLowBin]   = X['HighLowBin'].shift(i)
X[ColunmNameOpenCloseBin] = X['OpenCloseBin'].shift(i)
```